# Problem with the system command in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, system

I am using the system command in MATLAB as follows (with the current directory being 'scripts'):

```
[status, result] = system('cd ..\\TxtInOut')
```

However, invoking the system command does not seem to work. It returns `status = 0` and `result = ''`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

**If you want to change directories**, you should use the [CD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cd.html) command. The argument can be either a full path or relative path:

```
cd('c:\matlab\toolbox');  %# Full path to a directory
cd('scripts');            %# Move to a subdirectory "scripts"
cd('..\TxtInOut');        %# Move up one level, then to directory "TxtInOut"
```

**If you want information about a directory**, you should use the [DIR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html) command. [DIR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html) will return an `m-by-1` structure of information for a directory, where `m` is the number of files and folders in the directory. Again, the argument can be either a full path or relative path:

```
data = dir('c:\matlab\toolbox');  %# Data for a full path to a directory
data = dir('scripts');            %# Data for a subdirectory "scripts"
```

**NOTE:** When working on different platforms (i.e. Windows or UNIX), you will have to pay attention to whether you use the file separator `\` or `/`. You can get the file separator for your platform using the function [FILESEP](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/filesep.html). You can also build your file paths using the function [FULLFILE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fullfile.html).

Answer (score 3):

Any command executed by "system" is external to MATLAB. A command shell is generated, executes your request, and then returns the result. The 0 result indicates successful completion: the command shell changed its current directory as requested and then returned.  (Command shells use non-zero to indicate an error, because there are usually many more ways that a program can fail than succeed.) Unfortunately that only affects the command shell's current directory - see gnovice's answer for how to actually change the directory.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cd, dir, ls, etc directly in matlab without call system functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the underlying operating system commands by preceding them by an exclamation sign.

For instance:

- `!dir` will show you the current directory contents in Windows
- `!pwd` will show you the current directory in Linux/Mac

But calling `cd` does not change the current directory!